# Inserting videos from urls in beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to insert a video from url in Beamer, embedding, as follows:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=65]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{moreverb}

%% Video stuff
\usepackage{media9}

\newcommand{\myurlshort}[2]{\href{#1}{\textcolor{gray}{\textsf{#2}}}}



%%% Start of the presentation
\title{Adding video in a beamer presentation}
\author{By \myurlshort{http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~lcollado/}{L Collado-Torres}}
\date{
December 5th, 2012
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Youtube video}
\includemedia[
width=7.11cm,height=4cm,
activate=pageopen,
flashvars={
modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
&autohide=1 % controlbar autohide
&showinfo=0 % no title and other info before start
&rel=0 % no related videos after end
},
url % Flash loaded from URL
]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

However, the video does not open, even in the FoxReader.
Anyone can help me please, thinking in a solution for this?
(I need to use URL, not uploading the mp4 archive).

Comment: flash no longer works.

Comment: No have solution? Strange!

Comment: @AngeloAlianoFilho If you don't need a pdf as result, you could use the media2svg package

Comment: Use outro programa melhor pra isso. Simples.